# Selenium 4.11.0 for Java crashes on container image amd64/eclipse-temurin:20-alpine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

Running Selenium 4.11.0 for Java on a container with the following configuration crashes with the messages below.

```
FROM amd64/eclipse-temurin:20-alpine
RUN apk add chromium
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
WORKDIR /home/spring
COPY 'app.jar' /home/spring
```

Warning that the driver 115.x does not match the "chrome" version 116.x

```
Aug 25, 2023 7:18:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
WARNING: The chromedriver version (115.0.5790.170) detected in PATH at /usr/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (116.0.5845.96); currently, chromedriver 116.0.5845.96 is recommended for chrome 116.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
```

Crash of the runner because the browser process presumably crashes.

```
19:18:10.447 [main] ERROR de.xyz.xyz.xyz.SomeService - Failed to initialize web driver
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/spring/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Selenium 4.11.0 crashes on container image amd64/eclipse-temurin:20-alpine

When having a look into the distribution package repository of alpine the only versions that were available at that point in time where chrome driver 115.x and chromium 115.x, so both were matching. The mentioned version 116.x in the log messages seems to be odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Findings**

The path in the second error log contains a path to a cache. When checking the selenium documentation ([Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/)) there is now a automatic driver and browser resolution process in place. The chromedriver installed  in "usr/bin/chromedriver" from the distro repo is found by this manager, the browser is not. A binary is automatically downloaded which is of version 116.x and it seems to be a "real" chrome browser, not the "chromium" browser. Unfortunately the downloaded browser seems to crash immediately on startup. The presumably optimized chromium binary from the official distro repo just works.

```
~/.cache/selenium$

cat selenium-manager.json

{
  "browsers": [
    {
      "browser_name": "chrome",
      "major_browser_version": "",
      "browser_version": "116.0.5845.96",
      "browser_ttl": 1692994656
    }
  ],
  "drivers": [
    {
      "major_browser_version": "116",
      "driver_name": "chromedriver",
      "driver_version": "116.0.5845.96",
      "driver_ttl": 1692994688
    }
  ]
```

**Solution**

Set the path to the binary installed from the distro repository, this prevents the automatic download by the Selenium Manager.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1400,800");

options.setBinary("/usr/bin/chromium");

return new ChromeDriver(options);
```